# How to draw vectors with labels and grids?

Tags: pstricks, grids

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I would like to put this grid inside a document. But compiled, the grid appear to be out range. here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newrgbcolor{ttqqqq}{0.2 0 0}
\newrgbcolor{ffvvqq}{1 0.3333333333333333 0}
\psset{xunit=.3cm,yunit=.3cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=1.6pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-65.13952272980184,-73.04198685498632)(131.54227288116022,14.655307681913095)
\multips(0,-73)(0,10){9}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecap=1,dash=1.5pt 1.5pt,linewidth=0.4pt,linecolor=ttqqqq]{c-c}(-65.13952272980184,0)(131.54227288116022,0)}
\multips(-65,0)(10,0){20}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecap=1,dash=1.5pt 1.5pt,linewidth=0.4pt,linecolor=ttqqqq]{c-c}(0,-73.04198685498632)(0,14.655307681913095)}
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=red]{->}(70,0)(70,-15)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue]{->}(0,0)(-15,0)
\psline[linewidth=2pt]{->}(80,0)(95,0)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=green]{->}(85,-25)(75,-30)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue]{->}(0,0)(15,0)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red]{->}(15,0)(15,-15)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=green]{->}(15,-15)(5,-20)
\psline[linewidth=2pt]{->}(0,0)(5,-20)
\psline[linewidth=2pt]{->}(0,0)(0,-10)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted]{->}(0,0)(0,-15)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red]{->}(0,-15)(0,-30)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red]{->}(0,-30)(0,-45)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red]{->}(0,-45)(0,-60)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue]{->}(0,-60)(15,-60)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue]{->}(15,-60)(30,-60)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue]{->}(30,-60)(45,-60)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=blue]{->}(45,-60)(60,-60)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=green]{->}(60,-60)(70,-55)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=green]{->}(70,-55)(80,-50)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linestyle=dotted]{->}(0,-60)(80,-50)
\begin{scriptsize}
\psdots[dotsize=4pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](0,0)
\rput[bl](0.6709256491709888,1.1634162146978002){$A$}
\rput[bl](70.52894146830843,-7.38144838120522){\red{$\vec{v}$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=red](-15,0)
\rput[bl](-14.469974775148499,1.4632360250803622){\red{$B$}}
\rput[bl](-7.574119136349524,-0.6355026475975726){\blue{$-\vec{u}$}}
\rput[bl](87.4687607549233,0.713686499123957){$\vec{u}$}
\rput[bl](80.27308530574176,-28.069015297602007){\green{$\vec{w}$}}
\rput[bl](7.416871382778681,0.713686499123957){\blue{$\vec{u}$}}
\rput[bl](15.512006263107912,-7.38144838120522){\red{$\vec{v}$}}
\rput[bl](10.265159581413041,-18.025051649786175){\green{$\vec{w}$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=red](5,-20)
\rput[bl](5.617952520483296,-18.47478136536002){\red{$M$}}
\rput[bl](3.069484132231502,-9.780006864265717){$\vec{u}+\vec{v}+\vec{w}$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=red](0,-10)
\rput[bl](0.6709256491709888,-8.430817717544187){\red{$R$}}
\rput[bl](0.5210157439797068,-7.38144838120522){$\dfrac23\vec{v}$}
\rput[bl](0.5210157439797068,-22.37243890033333){\red{$\vec{v}$}}
\rput[bl](0.5210157439797068,-37.36342941946143){\red{$\vec{v}$}}
\rput[bl](0.5210157439797068,-52.35441993858954){\red{$\vec{v}$}}
\rput[bl](7.416871382778681,-59.250275577388464){\blue{$\vec{u}$}}
\rput[bl](22.407861901906887,-59.250275577388464){\blue{$\vec{u}$}}
\rput[bl](37.398852421035095,-59.250275577388464){\blue{$\vec{u}$}}
\rput[bl](52.3898429401633,-59.250275577388464){\blue{$\vec{u}$}}
\rput[bl](64.68245516584842,-56.851717094327974){\green{$-\vec{w}$}}
\rput[bl](74.57650890847304,-51.9046902230157){\green{$-\vec{w}$}}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=ffvvqq](80,-50)
\rput[bl](80.57290511612432,-48.45676240361623){\ffvvqq{$D$}}
\rput[bl](39.79741090409561,-54.30324870607619){$4\vec{u}-2\vec{w}$}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=ffvvqq](0,-60)
\rput[bl](0.6709256491709888,-58.50072605143206){\ffvvqq{$C$}}
\psdots[dotsize=4pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=ffvvqq](40,-55)
\rput[bl](40.54696043005202,-53.85351899050235){\ffvvqq{$T$}}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

It has to look like this picture below, It should be resized to 20x20 for example. Merci.

Using @marmot method with tikz I have this. How to put some of these vectors in dotted style?
here's the new code:

````latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc} 
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,>=stealth]
 \draw (0,0) grid (25,25) 
  (5,23) node[cross out,draw,thick,label={[anchor=south west]above:\contour{white}{$A$}}]{};
  \draw (2,23) node[cross out,draw,thick,label={[anchor=south west]above:\contour{white}{$B$}}]{};
  \draw (5,11) node[cross out,draw,thick,label={[anchor=south west]above:\contour{white}{$C$}}]{};
 \draw[thick,red,->] (16,23) -- ++(0,-3) node[midway,right] {\contour{white}{$\vec u$}};
 \draw[thick,blue,->] (18,23) -- ++(3,0) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$\vec v$}};
 \draw[thick,green!70!black,->] (18,19) -- ++(-2,-1) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$\vec w$}};
 \draw[thick,blue,->] (5,23) -- ++(-3,0) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$-\vec v$}};
 \draw[thick,red,->] (5,23) -- ++(0,-3) node[midway,right] {\contour{white}{$\vec u$}};
 \draw[thick,red,->] (5,20) -- ++(0,-3) node[midway,right] {\contour{white}{$\vec u$}};
 \draw[thick,red,->] (5,17) -- ++(0,-3) node[midway,right] {\contour{white}{$\vec u$}};
 \draw[thick,red,->] (5,14) -- ++(0,-3) node[midway,right] {\contour{white}{$\vec u$}};
 \draw[thick,blue,->] (5,20) -- ++(3,0) node[midway,above]
 {\contour{white}{$\vec v$}};
 \draw[thick,green!70!black,->] (8,20) -- ++(2,1) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$-\vec w$}};
 \draw[thick,gray!70!black,->] (5,23) -- ++(5,-2) node[midway,above]
 {\contour{white}{}};
 \draw (10,21) node[cross out,draw,thick,label={[anchor=south west]above:\contour{white}{$M$}}]{};
 \draw[thick,blue,->] (5,23) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{}};
 \draw (7,23) node[cross out,draw,thick,label={[anchor=south west]above:\contour{white}{$R$}}]{};
  \draw[thick,blue,->] (5,11) -- ++(3,0) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$\vec v$}};
  \draw[thick,blue,->] (8,11) -- ++(3,0) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$\vec v$}};
  \draw[thick,blue,->] (11,11) -- ++(3,0) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$\vec v$}};
  \draw[thick,blue,->] (14,11) -- ++(3,0) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$\vec v$}};
  \draw[thick,green!70!black,->] (17,11) -- ++(2,1) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$-\vec w$}};
  \draw[thick,green!70!black,->] (19,12) -- ++(2,1) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$-\vec w$}};
  \draw (21,13) node[cross out,draw,thick,label={[anchor=south west]above:\contour{white}{$D$}}]{};
   \draw[thick,gray!70!black,->] (5,11) -- ++(16,2) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{}};
   \draw (13,12) node[cross out,draw,thick,label={[anchor=south west]above:\contour{white}{$D$}}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}```

And we get this:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]


[![enter image description here][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/meEi8.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGRwQ.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKl8j.jpg
````

Comment: Where do all those decimal digits come from? Are they really indispensable?

Comment: The code looks like an export from a graphic program and is is more or less rubbish ... it is much more easier to write it directly inside the latex document

Comment: Exactly it is from geogebra with some modifications, reason why there’s lots of decimal

Comment: Sorry for asking so directly: you draw something with GeoCobra, have problems with the outcome, and ask others to convert it to some clean code? Wouldn't it make more sense if you tried to find out how to produce clean code yourself (you will see that this is much more fun than, say, GeoCobra or inkscape) and ask if there is a point at which you are stuck? How many others do you expect to benefit if someone replicates your grid precisely?

Answer (score 3):

Just for "comparison" purposes with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc} 
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,>=stealth]
 \draw (0,0) grid (25,25) 
  (5,23) node[cross out,draw,thick,label={[anchor=south west]above:\contour{white}{$A$}}]{};
 \draw[thick,red,->] (16,23) -- ++(0,-3) node[midway,right] {\contour{white}{$\vec u$}};
 \draw[thick,blue,->] (18,23) -- ++(3,0) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$\vec v$}};
 \draw[thick,green!70!black,->] (18,19) -- ++(-2,-1) node[midway,above] {\contour{white}{$\vec w$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the vectors in my code are different from these vectors. Actually my code is the answer to the grid you’ve made

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE I never made such a complicated grid, you must be confusing me with someone.

Comment: @ I edited my post

Answer (score 2):

A simple code with`pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit =6mm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(28,24)%
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame, labels=none, ticks =none](0,0)(28,24)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, gridlabels=0, griddots=10](0,0)(28,24)
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=x, PosAngle=90, dotscale =2](5,22){A}
\pnodes(19,22){R}(19,19){S}(21,22){B}(24,22){C}(22,18){G}(20,17){H}
\psset{linewidth=1.2pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12}
\ncline[linecolor=red]{R}{S}\naput{$\color{red}\vec{u}$}
\ncline[linecolor=blue]{B}{C}\naput{$\color{blue}\vec{v}$}
\ncline[linecolor=green]{G}{H}\nbput{$\color{green}\vec{w}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Merci Bernard for answering. I edited ly post

Answer (score 1):

Another short version:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=6mm}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{subgriddiv=1, gridlabels=0, griddots=10, gridcolor=black!20}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(28,24)%
\psframe(28,24)
\psdot[dotstyle=x,dotscale=2](5,22)\uput[90](5,22){$A$}
\psset{linewidth=1.2pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, shortput=nab}
\pcline[linecolor=red](19,22)(19,19)^{$\color{red}\vec{u}$}
\pcline[linecolor=blue](21,22)(24,22)^{$\color{blue}\vec{v}$}
\pcline[linecolor=green](22,18)(20,17)_{$\color{green}\vec{w}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The output depends on the compiler. If we use `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` then a dot is placed at `A` (not a cross sign). But if we use `xelatex` the dot becomes a cross sign.

Comment: No, it depends on your font setting. If you do not get a cross then the deafult `StandardSymL` font is not found by your `dvips`

Comment: OK. Thanks. I got a correct result with `pdflatex` and `auto-pst-pdf`.